# Datastore Quota Reached: Project quota page shows none reached

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, quota

I'm receiving this error on our App:

> The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.

However when I check out our quotas page, nothing is flagging as being over quota (or even close). We have billing enabled, we're not at our daily budget ($2 to test that it's not that - although normally $0) and these errors have been showing for over a minute (so I don't expect that it's the per-minute limits).

[image]

How can an API call fail due to being over quota, if everything seems to show that we're not over quota?

Comment: Can you share your project id privately? pcostello@google.com

Answer (score 0):

Budgets for API calls take a while to kick in. In this case, the project had hit the free limit for datastore operations (0.05M), however the increased daily budget had only just been enabled and so the app was still unable to use more of the operations.

This problem solved was solved after a couple of hours.

For others experiencing this issue, you can find the datastore free quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore). Compare your current usage on the view in the question to these limits. If it looks like you've gone over then re-assess where your daily budget is (or whether you need so many datastore calls!).